# Number of One to One Functions

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

Suppose a set A has n number of elements and a set B has m number of elements. Then why the number of one to one functions is n!?

And also, how many functions in total are possible? Are they n*m?

I think, they should be, n*m. Because, n*m would be total number of elements in A cross B. And since, you can't have a functions where an element of A won't be mapped to any element in B. Therefore, for every elements in A, you have m number of choices from B. That would make Product Rule applicable. And hence, they should be n*m. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks. :)

Comment: What is $N$?...

Comment: I'm sorry, that had to be, n! . I edited the question.

Comment: *Isn't* $n!$ except if $n=m$.

Comment: I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: You are wrong (in both cases). In the first case: see my answer. In the second case: you can choose **n times** an element of $B$ ($m$ to choose).

Comment: The question is badly formulated. To begin with you should say how the functions are related to the sets $A,B$: are they supposed to be functions $A\to B$, for instance?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity consider the following example

$A=\{a,b,c,d\} \quad \quad \quad \quad B=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$

In case of One-to-One for the first element $x_1$ of $A$ we have $7$ choices in $B$, for $x_2$ we have $6$ choices, for $x_3$ we have $5$ choices and for $x_4$ we have $4$ choices. So in general we have

$\quad \quad \quad \quad$ Number of One-to-One functions = $\frac {m!}{(m-n)!}$  $\quad \quad \forall m \geq n$

Similarly for a function from $A$ to $B$ implies that for $x_1$ in $A$ we have $7$ choices in $B$, for $x_2$ we have $7$ choices, for $x_3$ we have $7$ choices and for $x_4$ we have $7$ choices. So in general we have

$\quad \quad \quad \quad$ Number of functions = $m^n$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Necessary condition: $n\le m$. Number of injective functions form $A$ to $B$ = $n!\cdot$(number of subsets of $B$ with $n$ elements)

Number of functions form $A$ to $B$: *much greater* than $nm$.

Comment: How are number of number of injective functions form A to B = n! ?

Comment: $n!$ is the number of *bijective* functions form $A$ to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

For the total number of functions from A to B, you have the right thought starting with Therefore.  When you use the Product Rule, you are multiplying $n$ terms, each of them $m$, so the product is $m^n$